# Does kmalloc call type constructor?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kmalloc

It is known that memory allocation with **new** calls respective type constructor and memory allocation with **malloc** does not. But what about kmalloc?

I am trying to develop some system calls and I need to assign memory to a structure below.

```
struct mailbox{
    unsigned long existing_messages;
    unsigned long mxid;
    struct message *msg;
    struct message *last_node;
    mailbox(){
        existing_messages = 0;
        mxid = 0;
        msg = NULL;
        last_node  = NULL;
    }
};
```

If I allocate memory with **kmalloc** will it call constructor for **struct mailbox** at allocation time? if not what are the reasonable possible ways to get the constructor called **except** calling constructor explicitly. Is there any equivalent function as **new** for memory allocation in kernel?

Comment: Wait, how are you using C++ in the Linux Kernel? There's no such thing as constructors in C. Your code shouldn't even compile!

Comment: In kernel main make file I see a line **HOSTCXX = g++  HOSTCXXFLAGS = -O2** this means that when kernel compiles it is capable of compiling c++ code, Am I right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I highly doubt you would have much success... Sure, you might be able to get it to compile but I doubt you'd get anything useful out of it. The kernel doesn't support the C++ runtime AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kmalloc doesn't call constructor.

one way in C++ is to call "placement new".

example:

> void* ptr = malloc( sizeof(T) );
>
> T* p = new (ptr) T(); //construct object in memory

note:
you need to call destructor explicitly to avoid memory leaks in object itself,
and then call corresponding de-allocation routine for this memory.

> p->~T(); //call destructor
>
> free(ptr); //free memory